# CG Toolkit alternative?

Tags: opengl

I'm hoping there is an open source alternative to the CG toolkit. Only needs to compile high level OpenGL shaders though. Is there anything like this? I mainly need something like fx files.

Comment: OpenGL compiles GLSL shaders, and nobody else. There is nothing higher level than GLSL. It sounds to me like you're looking for some kind of FX format for OpenGL.

Comment: Yes I am looking for a FX format for OpenGL and CG Toolkit provides that. However, I need something I can compile for Android, but I can't get the source code for CG Toolkit to compile it for Android since it's not open source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only options are either to build your own effect library or use an incomplete opensource library such as GLFX.